# How does Mathematica evaluate sums where the upper limit of the index is not an integer?

Tags: evaluation, summation, indexed-variable, indexing

I am interested in the way Mathematica evaluates sums where the upper limit of the index is not an integer - i.e., sums that are some sense mathematically meaningless. For example:

```
{Sum[Cos[x - i], {i, 0, x}], Sum[Cos[x - i], {i, 0, Floor[x]}]} /. x -> 3.5

(*
 {-0.2892805393, -0.7892805393}
*)
```

The second number is clear and accurate. But what does that first number actually represent?

What assumptions has Mathematica made in order to be able to evaluate the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sum[foo[i], {i, 1, 3.5}]
```

> ```
> foo[1] + foo[2] + foo[3]
> ```

How `-0.289281` is obtained in the first case in OP: `Sum` evaluates before `ReplaceAll` takes effect:

```
Sum[Cos[x - i], {i, 0, x}]
```

> ```
> 1/2 (1 + Cos[x] + Cot[1/2] Sin[x])
> ```

```
% /. x -> 3.5
```

> ```
> -0.289281
> ```

You can see this using `Trace`:

```
Trace[Sum[Cos[x - i], {i, 0, x}] /. x -> 3.5] // Column
```

[image]